# Hibernate: overriding the (entity) superclass's OneToMany mapped field?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inheritance, many-to-one, hibernate-onetomany

Is it possible to make a subclass (entity) override a OneToMany mapping from its superclass (entity)?  Currently I'm getting "HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection", presumably because the superclass entity and subclass entity both link to the same list.

(My understanding is that @AssociationOverride can only be used when the superclass is @MappedSuperclass, not @Entity.  I do not want to change the superclass from @Entity to @MappedSuperclass, because I want the table for the superclass and the ability to query on it.)

How can I have Hibernate map something like the following?

```
@Entity
public abstract class PetOwner {
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Pet.class, mappedBy = "owner")
    public <T extends Pet> List<T> getPets()
    ...
}

@Entity
public abstract class Pet {
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = PetOwner.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public <T extends PetOwner> T getOwner()
    ...
}

@Entity
public class CatOwner extends PetOwner {
    @Override
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Cat.class, mappedBy = "owner")
    public List<Cat> getPets()
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Cat extends Pet {
    @Override
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = CatOwner.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public CatOwner getOwner()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I marked the subclasses' getters (CatOwner.getPets() and Cat.getOwner()) with @Override @Transient.